# Cobertura integration (for reports) should be integrated in Jenkins or SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I would like to integrate [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) in order to have reports for each build but I do not know what is the best place to integrated it.

Cobertura integration (for reports) should be integrated in [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube only accepts processed data, so you have to generate the data while running tests with a build-server (Jenkins in your case).

From the [SonarQube code coverage documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project):

> The Java Plugin is going to reuse reports and not generate them, so
>   before trying to configure your analysis to import these reports, you
>   need to be sure they are correctly generated and not empty.
>
> - The tests execution reports have to comply to the JUnit XML format.
> - The code coverage reports have to be generated by **Cobertura**, or JaCoCo
>     (details below).

You might need to configure something on the SonarQube side to import the data, but it should be generated on the build-server.

Technically the answer probably is that it should be integration in both.